# Retrieving SRC attribute of all HTML IMG tags on a webpage using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am attempting to write a script that locates the largest image on a page. The first step of this process would be to retrieve all the image sources on a particular website. This is where I am stuck.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function ImageFetcher(pageURL, partName) {
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {        
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
          headless: false,
        });
        const page1 = await browser.newPage();  
        await page1.goto(pageURL);    

        try {
            const images = await page.$$eval("img", els => els.map(x => x.getAttribute("src")));
            console.log(images);
        } catch(e) {console.log("ERR Locator")};

        await page1.close();
        await browser.close();
        return resolve();
      } catch(e) {console.log(`Error Image Fetcher Part Name: ${partName}`)};
    });
}

async function start() {
    pageURL = "https://www.grainger.com/product/NVENT-CADDY-Cushioned-Pipe-Clamp-1RVC3";
    partName = "10000";
    ImageFetcher(pageURL, partName);
} start();

//ERR Locator
```

Comment: You are declaring `page1` and then using `page.$$eval` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let testing = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
    headless: false
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://www.grainger.com/product/NVENT-CADDY-Cushioned-Pipe-Clamp-1RVC3');

  const image = await extractLargestImage(page);
  
  return image;
};

async function extractLargestImage(page) {
  return page.evaluate(() => {
    let imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    let largestImgSrc = 'none yet';
    let largestImgSize = 0;
    
    for (var img of imgs) {
      let imgSize = Number(img.height) * Number(img.width);

      if (imgSize > largestImgSize) {
        largestImgSize = imgSize;
        largestImgSrc = img.src;
      }
    }

    return largestImgSrc;
  });
}

testing().then((value) => {
  console.dir(value, {'maxArrayLength': null});
});
```

Comment: I realize OP accepted this so they're probably happy with it, but FYI this isn't sufficient to retrieve all images on the page -- many are lazy loaded and/or require interaction to access. For example, the image your code thinks is largest is https://static.grainger.com/rp/s/is/image/Grainger/1RVB9_AS01?hei=536&wid=536 but it's just a downsized version of https://static.grainger.com/rp/s/is/image/Grainger/1RVB9_AS01?hei=1000&wid=1000. If you strip the query params you can get the full-sized version. See the comments on the original post.

Comment: Good point, fortunately OP's website doesn't use lazy loading. I guess they wanted to retrieve the main product image thus the question was how to get the largest one otherwise if u wanted to get all images on any page, there are more efficient foolproof ways how to do it

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right about lazy loading. I was using `.getAttribute("src")` and this returns empty strings for many images. Good call on directly using `img.src`.